# RuntimeError: Group (<model>): Output not found for design variable 'paraboloid.x'

Tags: python, openmdao

I have been trying to run openmdao on my mac. Openmdao seems to be installed along with mpi4py but the code doesn't seem to be working. I have been getting the following error
"RuntimeError: Group (): Output not found for design variable 'paraboloid.x'."
The following is the code. This code is the example code provided in the openmdao get started page. Please help!

```
import openmdao.api as om

# build the model
prob = om.Problem()

prob.model.add_subsystem('paraboloid', om.ExecComp('f = (x-3)**2 + x*y + (y+4)**2 - 3'))

# setup the optimization
prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.model.add_design_var('paraboloid.x', lower=-50, upper=50)
prob.model.add_design_var('paraboloid.y', lower=-50, upper=50)
prob.model.add_objective('paraboloid.f')

prob.setup()

# Set initial values.
prob.set_val('paraboloid.x', 3.0)
prob.set_val('paraboloid.y', -4.0)

# run the optimization
prob.run_driver()

# minimum value
print(prob.get_val('paraboloid.f'))

# location of the minimum
print(prob.get_val('paraboloid.x'))
print(prob.get_val('paraboloid.y'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works only with OpenMDAO >= 3.2 (auto ivc feature). Check your version with the command `openmdao --version`. Otherwise you have to add IndepVarComp declarations (see [Conversion Guide for the Auto-IVC (IndepVarComp) Feature](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/other/auto_ivc_api_translation.html)).